# Early stopping on validation set

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, validation

There exist cases where one can "overfit" on the validation set. Although it is easier to overfit on the training set, the distributions of the validation and test set may not match, in which case tuning hyperparameters on the validation set could result in subpar performance on the test set.

It is common for neural networks to use early stopping on the validation set to determine what is a good place to stop training. However, in the scenario where there is a mismatch between the validation and test distributions, early stopping may result in lower performance. So, what are some alternatives to early stopping that could potentially address this issue?

Comment: Notice that same applies to whatever else you use your validation set for.

Comment: @Tim In this case, I'm only using it for early stopping.

Comment: Regularize the model, so that early stopping is not needed any more ?

Comment: @Thomas How does that help in terms of determining a stopping condition? You could try stopping at various epochs and look at *test* performance for each of those, but repeatedly querying the test set would not be good, right?

Comment: I was just provocative. Early stopping is a criterion to avoid overfitting, i.e. to stop the training at a point where the weights did not memorize patterns that are peculiar to the training set chosen. If one uses properly regularization, it is probably possible to reduce the capacity of a model, i.e. its capability to store information, to a level that cannot overfit, even if the training proceeds infinetely, but I was just provocative as I said I know it is a common procedure...

Comment: Essentially, you can avoid having stopping condition, at the precise of training several models with different capacities and choosing **on the trained models** which one is overfitting and which not...

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339412/163572

Answer (score 2):

"the distributions of the validation and test set may not match" it's normal that they do not match exactly. You should understand that training process is fitting your model weights to training data. However training data is only a part of whole problem. Training NN is based on belief that fitting to this samples would provide better quality of prediction on whole problem space. Usually you don't want to fit with much higher score on train that on validation set because it could leads your model to focus on very specific of part of space even if it leads to get worse score on whole space, which is called overfitting.

The question is when to stop training? Assuming you have: train, validation and test. Test couldn't be used in training process, so you can choose the best stopping point only based on train and validation, which naturally leads you to early stopping. You can also random guess how many epochs you need, which doesn't look better than early stopping. There is no other ways in general. In very specific problems you can use expert level domain knowledge.

Unfortunately if yours data is not representative for a problem the best solution is getting higher quality datasets.